# Can someone explain how the result arrive ? - CTE SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, common-table-expression

```
with CTE(x) as (
   select x = 1 
   union all 
   select X=X+1 from CTE where x < 4 
   union all 
   select X=X+1 from CTE where x < 4
)
select x from CTE 
GO
```

And the result Will be . .

```
x
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
4
4
3
3
4
4
4
4
```

Comment: Its a *Recusive CTE* i.e its repeatedly calling itself; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx

Comment: But it's an **unusual** recursive CTE.... typically, you'd join in your second part some data table with the CTE values already in place, to e.g. enumerate a hierarchy (select all the direct underlings of a given boss etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The

```
select x = 1
```

is called the anchor element. It is your base for the recursion call (As Alex K. pointed out this is a recursive CTE).

The 2 two's are coming from the recursive members

```
select X=X+1 from CTE where x < 4 
union all 
select X=X+1 from CTE where x < 4
```

being called on the anchor 1. The four 3's are coming from the recursive members being called on the two 2's, and lastly the 8 four's are coming from the recursive members being called on the 4 three's.

And from there it stops due to the condition

```
x < 4
```

Comment: It may also be worth noting that the order the numbers appear in comes from a depth first evaluation of this. That is once you have the 2s you process one of them to generate two threes, you then process one of the threes to get two fours which don't reprodeuce so you then process the next three and then you go back up to the second 2, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you just work through it bit by bit its pretty easy...

Firstly you have a 1.

Then that 1 creates two 2s from the UNIONs giving 1,2*,2* (the stars represent elements that are not yet processed).

You then process one of the 2s to give 1,2*,2,3*,3*. Note that the next one I processed was the most recent unprocessed element. This gives it a depth first rather than breadth first approach. The series then expands along those lines:

```
1
1,2*,2*
1,2*,2,3*,3*
1,2*,2,3*,3,4,4
1,2*,2,3,3,4,4,4,4
1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,3*,3*
1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,3*,3,4,4
1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,3,3,4,4,4,4
```

Fours are never needing to be processed so get no * mark.

Answer (score 0):

Select 1.

Take the selected value (1), add 1 and union it with the selected value plus 1. (2, 2)

Take the two rows just added (2, 2) and repeat. (3, 3)

...

"Four is right out."